# StatusBar flicker during activity transition android nouget

Tags: android, android-animation, android-transitions, activity-transition

**The Problem**

I have an Activity called Activity A which has the following transitions defined.

```
  @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
public static void slideAnimation(Window window) {
    //runs when the activity is being entered
    //runs in reverse when the activity is being destroyed
    Slide slideEnter = new Slide();
    slideEnter.setDuration(mShortAnimationDuration);
    slideEnter.excludeTarget(android.R.id.statusBarBackground, true);
    slideEnter.excludeTarget(R.id.app_bar_layout, false);
    window.setEnterTransition(slideEnter);

    //runs when the calling activity is exiting
    // runs in reverse when the activity is reentering
    Slide slideExit = new Slide();
    slideExit.setDuration(mShortAnimationDuration);
    slideExit.excludeTarget(android.R.id.statusBarBackground, true);
    slideExit.excludeTarget(R.id.app_bar_layout, false);
    window.setExitTransition(slideExit);


}
```

When I invoke Activity A everything works normal. The statusbar remains where it is but the appbar is animated into the screen. However when I run Activity B via A , the slideexit transition doesn't honor the statusbar. The status bar goes away however the appbar remains fixed (it is properly excluded from the animation).

**What I have tried**

If I comment out the code for slideexit and only keep the enter transition in A, the statusbar remains fixed during transition from A to B. This proves that the issue comes before B has been invoked. The issue is with the exittransition of A.

A's exit transition doesn't exclude the status bar and takes it off screen. B merely slides it back.

This is my styles.xml

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    <item name="android:windowContentTransitions">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowAllowEnterTransitionOverlap">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowAllowReturnTransitionOverlap">true</item>
</style>
```

This is how I invoke my activity

```
 void transitionTo(Intent i) {
    ActivityOptionsCompat transitionActivityOptions = ActivityOptionsCompat.makeSceneTransitionAnimation(getActivity(this), null);
    getActivity(this).startActivity(i, transitionActivityOptions.toBundle());
}
```

I am using nouget 7.0 on an HTC 10 with the support library version 24.2.1. 
I strongly believe that it is some framework issue as I clearly remember this working last year maybe 3 months ago or so.

Or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: There is a bug in nougat that will be fixed in O. The only solution to this is to share the backgrounds in your shared element transition.

Comment: Can you point us to the bug?